# C++ - Fastest possible bilinear interpolation?

Tags: performance, c++11, profiling, eigen

I would like to speed up my c++ bilinear interpolation code.

The setup is as following: **From a grayscale image *img* I want to extract a rectangular patch *pat* at position *cent* with unit spacing and no up-/downsampling.**

Since *cent* will generally not be integer, I have to bilinearly interpolate the extracted patch.

Image *img*, extracted patch *pat* and position *cent* are stored as floats.
The patch is of size [2*pad+1], with *pad* being the padding left and right of position *cent*.

The current solution looks like this:

```
void function(Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>* pat, 
              const float* img, 
              const Eigen::Vector2f* cent)
{

  Eigen::Vector4f we; // bilinear weight vector
  // ... [CROPPED: compute bilinear weights]

  float *pat_it = pat->data();
  for (y=cent[1]-pad; y <= cent[1]+pad; ++y)    
  {
    int postmp_a = y        * image_width;
    int postmp_b = (y-1)    * image_width;

    for (x=cent[0]-pad; x <= cent[0]+pad; ++x, ++pat_it)    
    {

          (*pat_it)     = we[0] * img[ x    +  postmp_a] +  
                          we[1] * img[x-1   +  postmp_a] +
                          we[2] * img[ x    +  postmp_b] +
                          we[3] * img[x-1   +  postmp_b]; 
    }
  }
}
```

1. **Is it possible to speed this up further?** This function will be called several millions of times in a real-time signal processing pipeline. **There is no memory constraint.**
2. Are there maybe specific Eigen functions for that?
3. Since this is the most crucial bottleneck of my code, I would also be willing to consider moving the code to different programming languages/architectures (Assembler, CUDA, etc...). Any thoughts/hints on this?
4. More generally, how would you systematically approach this for profiling?

Some more details: The Code is compiled with '-Ofast -std=c++11' and is already running in parallel using OpenMP. The image size is in the order of ~1000x1200 pixels, and *pad* between 5-10 pixels.

**EDIT**

I already managed to get a ~ 6 percent speed-up by using pointers to the 4 corresponding image locations directly.

```
...
for (x=cent[0]-pad; x <= cent[0]+pad; ++x,++pat_it,
     ++img_a,++img_b,++img_c,++img_d)    
{

      (*pat_it)   = we[0] * (*img_a) +  
                    we[1] * (*img_b) +
                    we[2] * (*img_c) +
                    we[3] * (*img_d); 
}
...
```

Comment: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/lerp-faster-cuda/ may be useful if you want to use CUDA.

Comment: Just looking at it, that inner loop begs for using pointers and unrolling, and I certainly would not count on the compiler's optimizer to figure that out. The only thing a profiler could tell you is if there is any speedup to be found elsewhere.

Comment: Before moving it to CUDA, I would suggest looking at rewriting that inner loop with SIMD intrinsics.This is x86, yes?  However, if you can or need to do multiple in parallel then CUDA may be the better option.

Comment: @Jez It works in [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fma/) as well.

Comment: What are your timings and what do you want/need them to be?

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg: The runtime is currently ~ 0.2  microseconds per function call. I will take any possible speed-up. Target is 0.1 microsecond.

Comment: Do you know `pad`? If you do, you can unroll the loop completely. If you know `image_width` in advance, you can maybe get rid of one or more pointers. You should be able to get it to the point where, if you step through it at the assembly language level, it is doing multiplying and adding and very little else. Certainly not a lot of indexing and loop-end-testing.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: With significant pipeline changed I can know pad and image_width at compile time. I simulated this and reduced the runtime from 0.19 microseconds to 0.165. This seems worth it. If you promote your comment to answer, and sketch how you would write it, I will accept this as answer.

Comment: @Jez If you are going to use CUDA why not go the whole distance and store the image in a texture unit and let the GPU do the lerping?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Suprusingly enough, a lot of Intel chips have no fma so the compiler has to generate code for it. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fma-qfma.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting Eigen to streamline some of it, something like:

```
void function(Eigen::VectorXf* pat, 
              const float* img, 
              const Eigen::Vector2f* cent)
{
...
  for (y=cent[1]-pad; y <= cent[1]+pad; ++y)    
  {
    ...
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array4f, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<>> mp(img + cent[0]-pad -1 +  postmp_b, 4, Eigen::OuterStride<>(image_width));
    for (x=cent[0]-pad; x <= cent[0]+pad; ++x, ++pat_it)    
    {
      new (&mp) Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array4f>(img + x-1 +  postmp_b, 4, Eigen::OuterStride<>(image_width));
      (*pat_it) = (mp * we.array()).sum();
...
```

Note: You might have to rearrange `we` to match the new order of the elements of `img`.

You can try and do even better by not creating a bunch of maps, but rather creating a single large one:

```
void function(Eigen::VectorXf* pat, 
              const float* img, 
              const Eigen::Vector2f* cent)
{
  ...
  Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXXf, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<>> mp(img, image_width, image_height, Eigen::OuterStride<>(image_width));
  for (y=cent[1]-pad; y <= cent[1]+pad; ++y)    
  {
    ...
    for (x=cent[0]-pad; x <= cent[0]+pad; ++x, ++pat_it)    
    {
      (*pat_it) = (mp.block<2,2>(x,y) * we.array()).sum();
...
```

You might be able to do better, I haven't tested any of this. Which leads me to the following disclaimer. I haven't tested this. Meaning, you may have to change around `InnerStride` and `OuterStride`, and `image_width` and `image_height`, etc.

If this helps you, I would love to know how much of a speedup it gives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like the last solution you presented: It gives the cleanest code. Unfortunately, it does not give a speed-up. My solution runs at .19 microseconds, yours at .24 microseconds. However: if the multiplication "   * we.array()  " is removed, the runtime is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by removed? You can also just declare `we` as a `Eigen::Array4f` and then there is no `.array()`. Also, if `img` is aligned, then the map should be declared with `Eigen::Aligned` instead of the `0`. This *might* enable SIMD operations.

Comment: 1) "Removed" meant ignoring we and summing mp.block() only. The runtime is still slightly higher than the original code. 
2) The image does not seem to be stored in an aligned state: The result changes, and the runtime increases. When using an empty dummy array which is aligned the runtime stays the same. I.e. SIMD operations are probably not used.